# Image of $\partial B_r $ under an holomorphic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f \colon & \mathbb C \setminus \left\{0\right\} \to \mathbb C  \\
& z \mapsto \frac{1}{2}\left( z+ \frac{1}{z}\right)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
I am asked to find the image of $\partial B_r := \{z \in \mathbb C : \vert z \vert = r\}$ (where $r >0$) under $f$.

Let me show you what I've done: hope it's correct.

Let $\vert z  \vert = r$. Then 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\vert f(z) \vert & = \sqrt{f(z) \overline{f(z)}} = \sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left( z+ \frac{1}{z}\right)\frac{1}{2}\left( \overline{z}+ \frac{1}{\overline{z}}\right)} = \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( z\overline{z} + \frac{z}{\overline{z}} + \frac{\overline{z}}{z} + \frac{1}{z\overline{z}}\right)} = \\ 
& = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( r^2 + 2\Re{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}} + \frac{1}{r^2} \right)}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now we calculate
$$
\Re{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}} = \Re{\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}} = \Re{\frac{x^2+y^2 + 2ixy}{x^2+y^2}} = 1
$$
hence we get 
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\vert f(z) \vert  & = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( r^2 + 2\Re{\frac{z}{\overline{z}}} + \frac{1}{r^2} \right)} = \\
& = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\left( r^2 + 2 + \frac{1}{r^2} \right)} = \frac{r^2+1}{2r} =: k.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So we can conclude that
$$
f(\partial B_{r}) = \partial B_{k} 
$$

What do you think? Is it correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you calculate $2\Re \frac{z}{\bar z}=\Re\frac{x+iy}{x-iy}$ What you get is $\Re \frac{x^2-y^2+2ixy}{x^2+y^2}$. So your calculation is wrong, then try to change everything accordingly.

Comment: You are right, sorry for my bad mistake. Now I try to fix it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know how to fix it. Have you got any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, writing $a+ib:=re^{it}$ that 
\begin{align}
f(re^{it})&=\frac 12\left(a+ib+\frac 1{a+ib}\frac{a-ib}{a-ib}\right)\\
&=\frac 12\left(a+ib+\frac{a-ib}{r^2}\right)\\
&=\frac 12\left(a\left(1+\frac 1{r^2}\right)+ib\left(1-\frac 1{r^2}\right)\right)\\
&=\frac 12\left(r\cos \theta\frac{r^2+1}{r^2}+ir\sin\theta\frac{r^2-1}{r^2}\right)\\
&=\frac 1{2r}(\cos\theta (r^2+1)+i\sin\theta(r^2-1)).
\end{align}
Do you recognize curve in the plane of the form $\gamma(t)=(A\cos t,B\sin t)$, where $A$ and $B$ are fixed?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now it's clear: the image of $\partial B_r$ is an ellipse with semiaxes $A=\frac{r^2+1}{2r}$ and $B=\frac{r^2-1}{2r}$. Well it was an easy problem, I'm sorry since I wasn't able to conclude it by myself. Anyway, Davide, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Just in case you wanted some more information, this is the Joukowski transform -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform .